# MongoDB Atlas mongorestore connection failure to respond in timely manner

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

Getting the following intermittent error message when doing a mongorestore to an Azure MongoDB Atlas cluster:

"
error running create command: connection(qa-tst-byn-aut-csh-usea-shard-00-02.ysjbm.mongodb.net:27017[-12]) incomplete read of message header: read tcp 192.168.251.2:52797->20.81.177.159:27017: wsarecv: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
"

How do I figure out why this is happening ?? What is best way to resolve ?

Comment: Check the whitelist in Atlas, and make sure you are explicitly telling mongorestore to use SSL/TLS.

Comment: thanks Joe, I should've mentioned above the issue is intermittent.Approx 6 out of 10 results in the message. The other times its fine. Should have nothing to do w/ TLS or not.

Comment: That specific error is a socket timeout.  If that is happening intermittently, I doubt the programming on either end has much to do with it.